# Filtro Java para páginas especificas

Tags: java, servlet, filter

Como faço o controle de acesso das páginas com Java? Tenho um filtro já implementado, que faz o controle se o usuário está ou não logado.

Porém, tenho uma página que preciso verificar a permissão do usuário... A página só vai ser acessada, caso o usuário seja administrador.

Quando o usuário for acessar a página de tratamentos e não for um usuário ADMINISTRADOR, a página não deve ser acessada.

Quero saber como fazer isso na parte de filtro em Java. O meu código é esse:

```
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, 
    FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    String context = request.getServletContext().getContextPath();

    try{
        HttpSession session = ((HttpServletRequest)request).getSession();
        User user = null;
        if(session != null){
            user = (User) session.getAttribute("user");

        }
        if(user == null){
            HttpServletResponse resp =((HttpServletResponse)response);

            resp.sendRedirect(context + "/");
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
            JPAUtil.closeEntityManager();
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muito simples amigo, no Banco De Dados, você terá que guardar o tipo de um usuário, administrador, ou cliente. Quando você for colocar o usuário na sessão, se certifique que o tipo dele está setado, no filtro você faria algo do tipo:

Primeiro você faz o mapeamento do Filter, no meu caso, todas as paginas que tiverem `"/admin/"` serão filtradas para que só os administradores tenham acesso.

**O mapeamento é feito assim**

```
@WebFilter(urlPatterns="/admin/*")
public class FilterAdm implements Filter
```

**Este é o método doFilter**

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    User user = (User) req.getSession().getAttribute("userSession");
    if (user == null || !user.getType().equals("adm")) {
        resp.sendError(400);
    } else {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }     
}
```

Espero ter ajudado !

Comment: Só que assim, vai dar resp.sendError(400) para todas as páginas... Mas só é pra isso acontecer, caso seja a página de tratamentos.

Comment: Então você deve fazer o mapeamento do Filter, desculpe, pense que iria entender, vou editar a resposta